# Remove prefix substring from string

Tags: tcl

I have a string `abc.def.ghi.j` and I want to remove `abc.` from that, so that I have `def.ghi.j`.

1) What would be the best approach to remove such a prefix which has a specific pattern?

2) Since in this case, `abc` is coincidentally the prefix, that probably makes things easier. What if we wanted `abc.ghi.j` as the output?

I tried it with the `split` method like this

```
set name abc.def.ghi.j
set splitVar [split $name {{abc.}} ]
```

The problem is that it splits across each of `a`, `b`, `c` and `.` seperately instead of as a whole.

Comment: The second argument to `split` is treated as a set of characters, not a substring.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, there's a few ways, but the main ones are using `string replace`, `regsub`, `string map`, or `split`-`lreplace`-`join`.

We probably ought to be a bit careful because we must first check if the prefix really is a prefix. Fortunately, `string equal` has a `-length` operation that makes that easy:

```
if {[string equal -length [string length $prefix] $prefix $string]} {
    # Do the replacement
}
```

Personally, I'd probably use `regsub` but then I'm happy with using RE engine tricks.

### Using `string replace`

```
set string [string replace $string 0 [string length $prefix]-1]
# Older versions require this instead:
# set string [string replace $string 0 [expr {[string length $prefix]-1}]]
```

### Using `regsub`

```
# ***= is magical and says "rest of RE is simple plain text, no escapes"
regsub ***=$prefix $string "" string
```

### Using `string map`

```
# Requires cunning to anchor to the front; \uffff is unlikely in any real string
set string [string map [list \uffff$prefix ""] \uffff$string]
```

### Using `split`…`join`

This is about what you were trying to do. It *depends* on the `.` being a sort of separator.

```
set string [join [lrange [split $string "."] 1 end] "."]
```